# Javascript module reveal and scoped jQuery in Drupal 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drupal, drupal-7

Alrightythen!

So I am busy with some javascript development inside drupal 7 pages. We basically have an MVC that hooks into a drupal page. Nothing fancy. Recently I started fixed legacy code that called jQuery.noConflict() to get an instance of jQuery because in drupal 7 jQuery is namespaced and the current dev did not know how to solve the dreaded '$ is not a function' issue without plastering every script with its own 'aliased' jquery instance like so:

```
$xj = jQuery.noConflict();
```

This causes a hole world of sh!z for any other code assuming $ is still available globally.

Now I have cleaned up all the noConflict calls and also wrapped all 'onload code' in this fancy closure:

```
(function ($) {
   // we can now use $ yo....
}(jQuery));
```

But now, sadly, I am being punished by the universe for using the javascript module reveal pattern. Let me try and explain by a code snippet: http://jsfiddle.net/yz41wr2g/

Does anyone have experience using namespaced jQuery in the module reveal pattern like this?

Comment: My first solution: http://jsfiddle.net/ou52v17a/
Only problem here is there will be considerable rewrite of existing modules

Comment: the other solution is to say, screw this namespace rubbish! I want my money!! =P 

$ = jQuery.noConflict();

Comment: Any reason you're not using the [pattern recommended by Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors)?

Comment: The code should be able to run in views that have not been embedded in drupal. So i can't write drupal specific modules.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my best attempt:

```
// drupal does this somewhere just to torture me!
jQuery.noConflict();

//this is my module reveal function/object
var MyModule = function ($) {
    //private members and functions                
    return {
        //public members and functions
        init: function () {
            alert($('.super-success').html());
        }
    };
}(jQuery);

// do 'onload' goodness here
(function ($) {
    // good news, now we have a reference to $
    alert($('.success').html()); // success!        
    MyModule.init();

}(jQuery));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6x0exhcp/1/

Please correct me if i'm wrong =)

Comment: I like this solution, AFAIK, this is the correct way to handle dependcies between modules: Dependency Injection. From the PoV of MyModule, jQuery is another module it depends on.

Comment: I almost added a comment on your answer but saw this comment now. I really wish there was some magic trick to avoid too much DI but I guess this is a slick as it's going to be. I think most of my frustration comes from legacy code that is poorly written (everything in global scope). I'm still pretty happy with this solution =) On a side-note, I think drupal might be messing with stuff that is not part of what a CMS should do...just my 2 cents

Comment: It surely depends on your definition of a CMS and what you expect from it. There is a part of Drupal which is not about managing the content itself, but rather about building the website with/around the content. That's the part that messes with JavaScript. And that's a part that many expect from their CMS.
DI is not something you avoid, DI is something your strive for. DI allows module decoupling. Decoupling is good for maintainability and testing.

Comment: DI is great if you don't have to refactor someone else's code ;) I use DI and loose coupling as much as possible for those exact reasons...

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to wrap all JavaScript code that depends on jQuery in an [immediately invoked anonymous function](http://stage.learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/functions/#immediately-invoked-function-expression-iife). This is not a Drupal thing, this is [a good practice when using jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/#protecting-the-alias-and-adding-scope). Drupal only force you to behave correctly because it behave correctly itself and does not want to prevent you from using another JavaScript library that use `$`.

```
// drupal does this somewhere to allow me to use another library that uses $
jQuery.noConflict();

(function ($) {
    // $ is now the jQuery object
    //this is my module reveal function/object, added to the global scope.
    window.MyModule = function () {
        //private members and functions                
        return {
            //public members and functions
            init: function () {
                alert($('.super-success').html());
            }
        };
    }();
    // do 'onload' goodness here
    alert($('.success').html()); // success!        
    MyModule.init();
}(jQuery));
```